# Results not going in pages for pagination in vueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, pagination, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap Vue to get some client side pagination working, with data coming in from a rest api. So far the pages get calculated but the results don't show on the pages, the results get shown outside and are not paginated. So the pages get calculated but the results are not on the pages. The component code so far is:

```
<template>
  <div class="container search">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">

 <div class="jumbotron mt-5" style="clear:both">
      <h1 class="display-4">{{title}}</h1>
      <p class="lead">{{intro}}</p>
      <hr class="my-4">
      <p v-if="validated" :class="errorTextClass">Enter a valid search term</p>

      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3"
        v-on:click="refreshPage"
        v-if="result.length > 1"
      >
        <font-awesome-icon icon="redo"/> Start again
      </button>
      <input
        class="form-control form-control-lg mb-3"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search"
        aria-label="Search"
        v-model="search"
        required
        autocomplete="off"
        id="search"
      >
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="rows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      aria-controls="my-table"
    ></b-pagination>

    <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

    <!-- <b-table
      id="my-table"
      :result="result"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small
    ></b-table> -->

     <div v-for="(result, index) in result" :key="index" :result="result"
      :perPage="0"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small >
        <div class="media mb-4">
          <img
            :src="resizeArtworkUrl(result)"
            alt="Album Cover"
            class="album-cover align-self-start mr-3"
          >
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="mt-0">
              <!-- <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3 float-right"
                v-on:click="addItem(result)"
              >
                <font-awesome-icon icon="plus"/>
              </button>-->

              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-3 float-right"
                v-on:click="addItem(result)"
                :disabled="result.disableButton"
              >

                <font-awesome-icon icon="plus"/>
              </button>

              <b>{{result.collectionName}}</b>
            </h4>
            <h6 class="mt-0">{{result.artistName}}</h6>
            <p class="mt-0">{{result.primaryGenreName}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>


      <div :class="loadingClass" v-if="loading"></div>

      <button
        class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block mb-3"
        type="submit"
        v-on:click="getData"
        v-if="result.length < 1"
      >
        <font-awesome-icon icon="search"/>Search
      </button>
    </div>



      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">


    <List :itemList="List"/>


      </div>


    </div>
    <!-- <div class='div' v-bind:class="[isActive ? 'red' : 'blue']" @click="toggleClass()"></div> -->


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import List from "../components/myList.vue";

export default {
  name: "Hero",
  components: {
    List
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      title: "Simple Search",
      isActive: true,
      intro: "This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style.",
      subintro:
        "It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out.",
      result: [],
      errors: [],
      List: [],
      search: "",
      loading: "",
      message: false,
      isValidationAllowed: false,
      loadingClass: "loading",
      errorTextClass: "error-text",
      disableButton: false,
      perPage: 3,
      currentPage: 1
    };
  },

  watch: {
    search: function(val) {
      if (!val) {
        this.result = [];
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    validated() {
      return this.isValidationAllowed && !this.search;
    },
    isDisabled: function() {
      return !this.terms;
    },
    rows() {
        return this.result.length
      }
  },

  methods: {
    getData: function() {
      this.isValidationAllowed = true;
      this.loading = true;
      fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${this.search}&entity=album`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.result = data.results;
          this.loading = false;
          /* eslint-disable no-console */
          console.log(data);
          /* eslint-disable no-console */
        });
    },

    toggleClass: function() {
      // Check value
      if (this.isActive) {
        this.isActive = false;
      } else {
        this.isActive = true;
      }
    },

    refreshPage: function() {
      this.search = "";
    },
    addItem: function(result) {
      result.disableButton = true; // Or result['disableButton'] = true;
      this.List.push(result);
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
      console.log(result);
      /* eslint-disable no-console */
    },

    resizeArtworkUrl(result) {
      return result.artworkUrl100.replace("100x100", "160x160");
    },

  },
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("List")) {
      try {
        this.List = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("List"));
      } catch (err) {
        console.err(err);
      }
    }
  },
};


</script>

<style>
.loading {
  background-image: url("../assets/Rolling-1s-42px.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.error-text {
  color: red;
}

.media {
  text-align: left;
}

.album-cover {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Any idea's or insight would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think vue bootstrap's pagination is meant to control default HTML divs. If what you want to do is display the result within the table you commented out, try changing it into this:

```
<b-table
      id="my-table"
      v-model="result"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small
    ></b-table>
```

In your previous implementation, b-table did not have any way to attach the array "result". What you did attach your array into was to a property named "result".

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know if is the same issue, but i have a grid component that only re-render if i force it, because the hole grid is mounted at "created" lifecicle, so you can try a nextTick(), would be something like this:

```
  <b-pagination v-if="renderPagination"
    v-model="currentPage"
    :total-rows="rows"
    :per-page="perPage"
    aria-controls="my-table"
  ></b-pagination>
```

Put a v-if directive observing a boolean variable, you can start it with true value at your data;

```
data() {
    return {
         renderPagination: true,
         // the rest of your data
    }
}
```

Then, after you consult your rest API for new data, call a logic with:

```
   this.renderPagination = false;
   this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.renderPagination = true;
    });
```

This will force the bootstrap component to re-render it self from start.